# Segmentation fault in C++ 5.1 but works fine in C++ 4.8.4

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, new-operator

I was working on [this](http://codeforces.com/contest/455/problem/B) problem and I had solved it using a trie. It runs fine for the testcases on my computer(uses GNU C++ 4.8.4 compiler), but it gives a segmentation fault(runtime error 11) on Codeforces Judge as well as Ideone for C++11 (G++ 5.1) . Infact, it works fine in C++ 4.3.2 on Ideone for the same testcase

```
2 3
a
b
```

This is my code.

```
    #include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

typedef struct node
{
    int status;
    int visited;
    struct node *children[26];
}node;

node *gen_node()
{
    node *newnode=new node();
    newnode->status=0;
    newnode->visited=0;
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        newnode->children[i]=NULL;
}

void insert(node *root,string s)
{
    int n=s.size();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if(root->children[s[i]-'a']==NULL)
        {
            root->children[s[i]-'a']=gen_node();
        }
        root=root->children[s[i]-'a'];
    }
}

void dfs(node *root)
{
    root->visited=1;
    int flag=0,i;
    for(i=0;i<26;i++)
    {
        if(root->children[i]!=NULL && (root->children[i])->visited==0)
        {
            dfs(root->children[i]);
            flag=1;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
        root->status=0;
    }
    else
    {
        root->status=0;
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            if(root->children[i]!=NULL)
            {
                root->status=(root->status)|(!((root->children[i])->status));
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n,k;
    cin>>n>>k;
    node *root=gen_node();
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        string s;
        cin>>s;
        insert(root,s);
    }
    dfs(root);
    if(root->status==0)
    {
        cout<<"Second"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        int flag=0;
        for(i=0;i<26;i++)
        {
            if(root->children[i]!=NULL)
            {
                if((root->children[i])->status==1)
                {
                    flag=1; //root has atleast one losing strategy
                }
            }
        }
        if(flag==0)
        {
            if(k%2==0)
            {
                cout<<"Second"<<endl;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<"First"<<endl;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"First"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I had tried debugging on Ideone( No way to use gdb :( ), and found that the segfault happens here in insert() function (through commenting and uncommenting).

```
if(root->children[s[i]-'a']==NULL)
        {
            root->children[s[i]-'a']=gen_node();
        }
```

I am not sure how this happens. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: You're not returning anything from `gen_node`.

Comment: But why is it running fine on C++ 4.3.2?

Comment: It isn't "fine". It just may appear to be.

Comment: Is it like the function returns a dummy instance of node if I don't return anything?

Comment: No, your code is broken and you need to fix it. There are no guarantees about what it may do.

Comment: @RameshwarBhaskaran You're not returning what you claim you will, and step off the cliff of *undefined behavior* thereafter. Regarding "why is it running fine" : stop equating *defined* behavior with *observed* behavior. The former can lead to the latter; the latter is too-often mistaken to be synonymous with the former. Consider yourself fortunate it was tested where it exhibited its malaise. Imagine the tragedy if you hadn't and it made its way to someplace where it *really* mattered. (like a grade, or worse, a customer).

Comment: It's not "C++ 4.3.2". It's *GCC* 4.3.2. Don't mix up the language version with the compiler's...